# Quartz Scheduler create schedulerFactoryBean Beans without quartz.properties

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have running quartz scheduler  with inside my spring app.

right now, i'm using quartz.properties to contain any properties value and use it to create schedulerFactoryBean Bean and it works fine.

this is my QuartzConfiguration..

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    public static final String CONTEXT_KEY = "applicationContext";

    //@Autowired
    //private DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey(CONTEXT_KEY);
        scheduler.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("config/quartz.properties"));
        //scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        //scheduler.setAutoStartup(true);
        scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

My quartz.properties :

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver =oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@example:1521:db
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = user
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1 from dual
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = DPPA.QUARTZ_
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.class=id.co.fifgroup.dpa.batch.BatchHistoryListener
```

i want to create schedulerFactoryBean without any quartz.properties, because my client dont want to change any database connection inside the war archieve.

is it possible to create schedulerFactoryBean without any quartz.properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it without properties file in this way;

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "Scheduler_test");
p.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", 2);
...
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(p);
```

Comment: by doing it like this ` Properties p = new Properties();` and `scheduler.setQuartzProperties(p);`